# Index is not used when joining two tables in a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, index, join, mysql-5.7

In MySQL 5.7, I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `periodholdings ` (
   `stkcode` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `participantid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `participantname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `holdingdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
   `shares` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   `percentage` decimal(5,4) DEFAULT NULL,
   KEY `sp` (`stkcode`,`participantname`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `pholdings` (
   `stkcode` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `participantid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `participantname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `holdingdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
   `shares` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   `percentage` decimal(5,4) DEFAULT NULL,
   KEY `sp` (`stkcode`,`participantname`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `choldings` (
   `stkcode` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `participantid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `participantname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `holdingdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
   `shares` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   `percentage` decimal(5,4) DEFAULT NULL,
   KEY `sp` (`stkcode`,`participantname`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In the SP, I called the following:

```
    drop table if exists pholdings;
    create table pholdings (index sp(stkcode, participantname)) as select * from periodholdings where holdingdate = '2016-09-01'; 

    drop table if exists choldings;
    create table choldings (index sp(stkcode, participantname)) as select * from periodholdings where holdingdate = '2016-09-21'; 

   explain
    (select p1.stkcode, p1.participantid, p1.participantname, if(c1.shares is null, -p1.shares/100, (c1.shares - p1.shares)/100) as averagediff from pholdings p1 use index(sp) left join choldings c1 use index(sp) on p1.stkcode = c1.stkcode and p1.participantname = c1.participantname)
    union
    (select c1.stkcode, c1.participantid, c1.participantname, if(p1.shares is null, c1.shares/100, (c1.shares - p1.shares)/100) as averagediff from pholdings p1 use index(sp) right join choldings c1 use index(sp) on c1.stkcode = p1.stkcode and c1.participantname = p1.participantname);
```

However, the index is not used at all.

```
1   PRIMARY p1      ALL                 407340  100.00  
1   PRIMARY c1      ALL sp              412439  100.00  Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
2   UNION   c1      ALL                 412439  100.00  
2   UNION   p1      ref sp  sp  1535    ccass.c1.stkcode,ccass.c1.participantname   70012   100.00  
    UNION RESULT    <union1,2>      ALL                         Using temporary
```

If I just put the last EXPLAIN statement into the query and modify a little (like exchange the `c1` and `p1` around the `=`), the index works again.

Comment: And if you remove all the `use index`, what happens?

Comment: The same. Also I tried with force index. Doesn't work. However, after run the whole block then  if only run the explain statement by changing like c1 = p1 to p1 = c1, the index works. So weird. I suspect it's a MySQL 5.7.15's bug.

Comment: `FULL` would be more efficiently done with `UNION ALL`: `SELECT .. FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON ... UNION ALL SELECT ... FROM a RIGHT JOIN b ON ... WHERE a.x IS NULL;`

Answer (score 0):

`Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)` is perhaps better than using an index.  It loaded the entire table in RAM so it can quickly probe it.

You seem to be simulating a `FULL OUTER JOIN`?  That can be made more efficient...

- Create only one tmp table; then use a combination of the original and the tmp table.
- Don't include the "intersection" in both parts of the `UNION`, thereby necessitating `UNION DISTINCT` (which is what you have), but rather the faster `UNION ALL`.
- `periodholdings LEFT JOIN tmp` gives you the intersection and NULLs on one side
- `tmp LEFT JOIN periodholdings ... IS NULL` gives you the other lobe of the Venn diagram.

Other issues...

- If (`stkcode`,`participantname`) is unique, make it the `PRIMARY KEY`; that will speed things up.
- Why have a `name` and `id` in the same table?  Shouldn't this be "normalized" into another table?
- Don't blindly use `(255)`; pick something smaller, but sufficiently big.  This will speed up any tmp tables needed.
- `decimal(5,4)` - You are not going over 9.9999?

Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`; it may provide some more details.

Comment: It is not better than using an index. Once the index is selected by optimiser, it is done in seconds. Otherwise, it not ends.

A: Why have a name and id in the same table? Shouldn't this be "normalized" into another table?
Q: Not every name has an ID. This is something from government web. Even worse, the name could be changed if the company is sold to others. So only ID is unique but not every name has an ID. That's what I am suffering.

A: decimal(5,4) - You are not going over 9.9999?
Q: Yes. It is a percentage field. The maximum number is 1.

(stkcode,participantname) is not unique.

Comment: I tried mysql check. After rebuilding all statistics, the query can make use of the index and the pastdiff is created fast. However, in stored procedure, the index still can not be used. I wondered why. Besides, the char set of the SP and the mysql is the same. Both are UTF8.

Comment: What is pasdiff?  _Perhaps_ recreating the SP would fix its problem.  By "rebuilding all statistics", do you mean `ANALYZE TABLE`?

Comment: In Hong Kong, every financial institution will report their holdings of every stocks they have everyday. If the institution do not have certain stock, they will not report. The current holding of today is in choldings. The holdings of previous business day is in pholdings. The difference of one stock holdings of the same institution between today and prev b-day is in pastdiff. By "rebuilding all statistics", I mean runt he command line of mysqlcheck --auto-repair --optimize --all-databases. I have recreating the SP by drop and import again, keeping the charset the same as DB both are UTF8.

Comment: Now, in the SP I have to force the index which will work however ugly.

Comment: As a side note, you may need utf8mb4 instead of utf8.  (Some Chinese institutions may have non-BMP characters in their names.)

Comment: Since you are using InnoDB, you don't need repair, optimize, or check.

Comment: If (`stkcode`,`participantname`) is UNIQUE, then make it the `PRIMARY KEY`.